# Electrical schematic symbol help(looks like an or gate)

Tags: schematics, design, logic-gates, symbol, analysis

I'm wondering if that little dot represents anything?

[image]

Comment: what is your question? ... you did not ask one

Comment: The bubble indicates signal inversion because one side of the wire is active-low, and the other side of the wire is active-high. So it is a “free” logical inversion due to the way the input and output signals were defined. The bubble is just a reminder that this is a mixed-logic system, with a logical inversion happening there.

Comment: Thank you, Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot represents inversion. It's an OR gate with one input inverted.

An equivalent circuit is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWVJdgm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Imagine the triangle part of the inverter disappearing, and you'll see the resemblance.)

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the logic symbols, the bubble represents the inversion. Whatever is the signal, the bubble inverts that signal. For example, in the picture AND gate is used.
 [image: logic gate]

The output should be logic 0 but due to bubble at output, the output of gate changed to logic 1.